# Every Automorphism of a Tree Fixes an Edge or a Vertex Algebraic Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, trees, permutation-cycles

I need to show every automorphism of a tree fixes an edge or a vertex. I am aware of the classic inductive proofs of this fact, but I wanted to try this algebraically. I am fairly new to graph theory so I am not sure if this is a valid method.

Consider Tree $T = (V,E)$. Then an Automorphism of $T$ can be represented by permutation cycles of the vertices or a permutation cycle of edges. Since a tree has $v$ vertices and $v-1$ edges $\implies$ either the permutation of edges or the permutation of vertices must be even depending on $v$. But of course, every even permutation is a product of $3-cycles$.

It can easily be checked by hand or by a computer that any permutation of a $3-cycle$ of vertices of $T$ fixes a vertex or edge. Similarly, a $3-cycle$ of edges of $T$ fixes an edge or a vertex. So, since any automorphism of $T$ can be written as a product of $3-cycles$, then $T$ must fix an edge or vertex.

Any help showing if this is valid, or why it is invalid would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if the vertex fixed by one three-cycle is moved by another?

Comment: This is a good point. So, I suppose this would only necesarilly be true if we could insist that the three-cycles are disjoint, which I do not think we can say.

Comment: We cannot, alas.

Comment: Would you be interested into an algebraic topology proof? The result can probably be derived from Brouwer fixed-point theorem, or another fixed-point theorem.

Answer (score 4):

It is not fair to conclude that because one of $|V|$ or $|E|$ is even, the permutation of either $V$ or $E$ must be even.

For example, consider the tree

```
    b
    |
    |
a---e---c
    |
    |
    d
```

and consider the automorphism that swaps $a,b$ (leaving $c,d,e$ fixed). This is an odd permutation of the vertices (because two vertices are swapped), and also an odd permutation of the edges (because the edges $ae, be$ are swapped, leaving the other edges alone).

Even a permutation of an even set with no fixed points can be odd. For example, we can permute $\{1,2,3,4\}$ by $(1\;2)\;(3\;4)$ (an even permutation) or by $(1\;2\;3\;4)$ (an odd permutation).